# How to use Background tasks in Android with an API level less than 26

Tags: java, android

I've been looking for a way to make alerts in the background of the device ,and I found a way to work with devices that are less than 26 api 
can you help me to finish the code?
How to use it ?
What's the rest of the code?
[enter link description here](https://hackernoon.com/background-ble-scan-in-doze-mode-on-android-devices-mx8o37my)

```
// the code 
public class NavigineReceiverExample extends BroadcastReceiver {

      // here you need to receive some action from intent and depending on this action start service or set repeating alarm
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String  action = intent.getAction();

        try{
          if (action.equals("START")) {        
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0,
                new Intent("WAKE"),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            if (alarmService != null)
              alarmService.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
          } else if (action.equals("WAKE")) {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, NavigineService.class));
          }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
          Logger.d(TAG, 1, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is not working with the existing code?

Comment: I want to write the rest of the code